# ApplicationCharge and test mode

Tags: shopify

If I enable test mode for a (recurring) charge in my Shopify App during beta

```
charge = ShopifyAPI::RecurringApplicationCharge.create(:name => 'myplan', 
  :price => 4.99, :return_url => 'http://yourapp.com/charges/confirm',
  :test => true)
```

what should I do when the App goes out of beta? Can I just update the existing (recurring) charge, or do I have to create a new (recurring) charge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should cancel the test charge and create a new one. You will need to redirect the shop owner to the new charge confirmation url, as they'll need to accept the new charge. It's not possible to change the charge without the shop owner's permission as far as I know, except to cancel it.